# Wordpress missing break lines

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I've got a wired problem here... One of my clients tells me that there is no `<p></p>` or `<br/>` tags in her posts, and i've checked my self... wtf is wrong?

Example on how it should be (visual)

[image: visual]

This is how the HTML looks like, with no break lines? :S

[image]

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Wordpress's Editor's 'source view' still isn't actual source. Try looking at the generated HTML of the page by actually accessing it with a browser.

Comment: @Sammitch already done that, still missing the <p><br/></p> tags etc

Comment: How is the content displaying? Can you provide the markup that the user typed into the editor?

Comment: Go into functions.php, and look for `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` If you see that anywhere, comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check your theme's functions.php file, its possible your missing the wordpress wautop function as seen here: http://codex.wordpress.org/How_WordPress_Processes_Post_Content#wpautop.28.29_WordPress_Function

You can also disable this function and use your own content filtering methods... this blog should help for that: http://blog.bigsmoke.us/2010/12/09/wpautop